# Android Navigation Drawer without fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer, sidebar

I have developed an Android Application with multiple activities as a module.
Now I want to integrate all the activities using the sidebar(navigation drawer).

I have searched on internet about it but everything seems to be using fragments. I have no idea how can I achieve this.

Can anyone tell me how can I integrate everything with sidebar.
I haven't used Action-bar on top of activities I just want to put a button on top left corner which will open sidebar and I can use it.

If I ll need fragments, can I get a help on that?

Comment: Create a `BaseActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity` with Drawer. And Make all other activities to extends `BaseActivity`. WhereAs its better if you use fragments with a single activity .

Comment: How to convert my activities to fragments?

Comment: By writing code in fragment . Read the fragment with drawer tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement Navigation Drawer using `NavigationView` which is the best and simplest way to implement it. Now you have to use fragment for Navigation items click because in every item click a new layout appears, but notice one thing you still can access navigation drawer by clicking on default hamburger icon, so conclusion is this you have to use fragment because user can access drawer from all screen which appear after item click of navigation drawer. [see tutorial here](https://www.journaldev.com/12648/navigationview-android)

Comment: I havent used actionbar on top of the layout. So how can I use it. and can you suggest me how can I convert all my activities to fragments?

Comment: You have to add toolbar in your layout file and in java code use ActionBarDrawerToggle for hamburger icon animation. For changing your Activity to Fragment my suggestion is to create a separate fragment then copy your activity code to fragment